# How to loop through two xml files?

Tags: php, xml

I have two xml files that look like this:

First:

```
<numbers>
<line><value>a1</value></line>
<line><value>a2</value></line>
<line><value>a3</value></line>
</numbers>
```

Second:

```
<numbers>
<line><value>b1</value></line>
<line><value>b2</value></line>
<line><value>b3</value></line>
</numbers>
```

Right now I have double foreach loops (I know it should be something else, for loop maybe?)

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xmldata2 = simplexml_load_file('file2.xml');
    foreach($xmldata->line as $item){
        foreach($xmldata2->line as $item2){
            echo $item->value;
            echo $item2->value. "</p>";

        }
    }
```

But the output is this:

```
a1b1
a1b2
a1b3
a2b1
a2b2
a2b3
a3b1
a3b2
a3b3
```

Should be:

```
a1b1
a2b2
a3b3
```

Comment: Are they always the same size?

Comment: Files are not always the same size, program should print out first value from first xml file + first value from the other file. Then on the new line second value from first file and second value from second file etc.

Comment: And what if one file is bigger then the other?

Comment: I changed the numbers so it should be easier to understand now.

Comment: Lets say the loop goes as many times as the length of the shorter file for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the logic but this would achieve what you say you want to achieve.

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xmldata2 = simplexml_load_file('file2.xml');
$key = 0;
foreach($xmldata->line as $item){

    echo '<p>';
    echo $item->value;
    echo $xmldata2->line[$key]->value;
    echo "</p>";
    $key++;
}
```

RESULT

```
<p>a1b1</p>
<p>a2b2</p>
<p>a3b3</p>
```

But if it is possible that the 2 xml files may not be the same length this might be safer.

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xmldata2 = simplexml_load_file('file2.xml');

// only loop for the number of occurances in the smallest xml file
$max = count($xmldata) >= count($xmldata2) ? count($xmldata2) : count($xmldata);

for ($key=0; $key < $max; $key++){

    echo '<p>';
    echo $xmldata->line[$key]->value;
    echo $xmldata2->line[$key]->value;
    echo "</p>";
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I thought that was a volunteer not the OP.  You might consider `min()` then.

Comment: Hmm, `min()` seems to be having one of its unpredictable moments with this data. If the second file is smaller than the first, `min()` gets it wrong..... unless its me having one of those unpredictable moments :) @mickmackusa

Comment: Ahh but can you explain this @mickmackusa https://3v4l.org/dQCdg When first file is larger than second it incorrectly calc the min occ

Comment: You are counting the min value of the two objects https://3v4l.org/NbKet (always 1) -- that was not my suggestion.  I suggested counting both then finding the min() of the two counts.

Comment: :) The always 1 issue was due to a typo of mine in code I added at the last minute.... see the line echo '>>>>>min calculated as ' . $stop_loop . PHP_EOL>PHP_EOL; and replace the > with a . @mickmackusa https://3v4l.org/tNDOk

Comment: Again, my suggestion seems to work as I expect. https://3v4l.org/rAnDq Your way seems to reveal that `min()` is object-intolerant or something.

Comment: AHhhh finally I see the difference between out code :) I used this example `$val = min(array(2, 2, 2), array(1, 1, 1, 1));` to test for min, and that appears to be causing issues where as you count the arrays and then do a min of the 2 counts.